# Example of Non-Cancellative Commutative Monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Can anyone help to give an example of non-cancellative commutative monoid? Maybe like, $S_n = \{1,2,3...,n\}$ and a map of $S_n \times S_n \to S_n$.

Thanks.

Comment: How about ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$, where $n$ is composite? If $n=ab$, then $ab\equiv 0b\pmod n$ even through $a\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: (where multiplication is the monoid operation).

Comment: @Earnest that's right. Thanks.

Comment: @Earnest yeah, for a little simplification of your answer, any map from Sn = {0, 1,... n-1}, Sn * Sn -> Sn where n is composite, and the map acts the same as mod.

Comment: Even more simply, let $*$ be defined by $x*y=1$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @ Earnest, that's very general now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any commutative ring $R$ that is not $0$, $(R, \times)$ is not cancellatuve. It's even "less" cancellative is $R$ is not an integral domain.

Examples include $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n$ a nonprime non integer; but also infinite rings such as the ring of continuous (or smooth) functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$; or for any commutative ring $R$ and integer $n\geq 2$, $R^n$, and many more.

Comment: what do you mean "can not form a group" ?

Comment: I think your answer is correct and very general. But it somewhat from the Idea of a Ring. Wondering if there's any insight for just the relationship between cancellativity and the commutative monoid.

Comment: @Max Well... this answer can be even more general. The multiplicative monoid of *any nonzero commutative ring* is non-cancellative (because of $0$) . The fact that $R\setminus\{0\}$ is a cancellative monoid iff $R$ is a domain never really comes into play.

Comment: @rschwieb : indeed, let me modify that to give "interesting" examples !

Comment: If R is a commutative ring that is not a domain, then $(R \setminus \{0\}, \times)$ does not make sense: By definition, if R is not a domain, there exist $a, b \neq 0$ such that $a \times b = 0$.

Comment: @name : oops you're right; $(R, \times)$ still works though

Answer (score 2):

The set of all the subgroups of a group $G$ is a commutative monoid under set intersection, with $G$ the identity element. Say $\mathcal G$ this monoid. We get:

1. $G$ is the only invertible element of $\mathcal G$;
2. the subset of all the normal subgroups of $G$ is a submonoid of $\mathcal G$.

$\mathcal G$ is non-cancellative, as $H\cap H=H\cap G$ for every $H\in\mathcal G\setminus\{G\}$, but $H\ne G$.

Comment: Or you could say subalgebras of some algebra, or subsets of some set, also under intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf S = \langle S, \vee, 0\rangle$ be a semilattice with bottom element.
Thus $\langle S, \vee\rangle$ is a commutative idempotent semigroup and $s\vee 0 = s$ for every $s \in S$.

So $\mathbf S$ is a monoid.
But if $S$ is nontrivial, say $s \in S\setminus\{0\}$, then
$$s\vee0 = s = s\vee s,$$
so $\mathbf S$ is not cancellative.

---

More generally if $a,b \in S$ and $a\neq b$, then, with $c=a\vee b$, we have
$$a\vee b = c = a \vee c = c \vee b,$$
so, if $\mathbf S$ were cancellative, then we would have $a=c$ and $b=c$, a contradiction.